# Magento custom "order" attribute / admin input and display

Tags: magento, model, attributes

I need to add a custom attribute to the order model ("**dynamics_ord**").

This attr needs to be defined by admin staff, after the order has been successfully saved, ideally on the **admin/sales_order/view**, in the main order block.

It needs to be independent of invoice / shipment etc - maybe attached to an order "`edit`" event.

I've made a number of custom attributes for other entities (notably - customers). And I realize this is the same process. But I'm not clear how to go about amending an order with this attribute, as there is no obvious "update" action. "Edit" may make sense, but I'd rather not duplicate orders needlessly.

Once this attr is in place, I want to display it in the **sales_order/index** grid.
(Note = check out [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695352/magento-add-custom-attribute-column-to-sales-order-index-grid) for a working solution.)

**Final State of this module** (and for anyone else in need of this solution):

**/sales_order/view/** screenshot :
[image: Screenshot]

**WACI_SalesExt**

```
app/local/WACI/SalesExt
 /Block
   /Adminhtml
     /Sales
       -Dynamicsord.php
 /controllers
   /Adminhtml
     /Sales
       - OrderController.php
 /etc
  - config.xml
 /Helper
   - Data.php
 /sql
   /waci_salesext_setup
     -mysql4-install-0.2.0.php
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <WACI_SalesExt>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </WACI_SalesExt>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <helpers>
            <WACI_SalesExt>
                <class>WACI_SalesExt_Helper</class>
            </WACI_SalesExt>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <WACI_SalesExt>
                <class>WACI_SalesExt_Block</class>
            </WACI_SalesExt>

            <adminhtml> <!-- unclear if i need this second declaration for admin-->
                <WACI_SalesExt>
                    <class>WACI_SalesExt_Block</class>
                </WACI_SalesExt>
            </adminhtml>

        </blocks>

        <models>
            <WACI_SalesExt>
                <class>WACI_SalesExt_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>salesext_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </WACI_SalesExt>

        </models>

        <resources>
            <waci_salesext_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>WACI_SalesExt</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </waci_salesext_setup>
            <waci_salesext_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </waci_salesext_write>
            <waci_salesext_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </waci_salesext_read>
        </resources>

    </global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <WACI_SalesExt after="Mage_Adminhtml_Sales">WACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml</WACI_SalesExt>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>
</admin>
</config>
```

**WACI / SalesExt / sql / waci_salesext_setup / mysql4-install-0.2.0.php**

```
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $installer->addAttribute('order', 'dynamics_ord', array(
                                'type'              =>'varchar', 
                                'visible'           => true, 
                                'required'          => false, 
                                'is_user_defined'   => false, 
                                'note'              => 'Dynamics ORD')
                            );

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order'), 'dynamics_ord','VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order_grid'), 'dynamics_ord','VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL');

    $installer->endSetup();
```

**template/sales/order/view/info.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('WACI_SalesExt/adminhtml_sales_dynamicsord')->setOrderId($_order->getId())->toHtml() ?>
```

**template/sales/ord_form.phtml**

```
<?php if ('sales_order' == Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() ): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="label"><label for="dynamics_ord">Dynamics ORD</label></td>
    <td class="value">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getFormUrl(); ?>" method="post" id="ord_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $this->getToken(); ?>" />  
            <div class="">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" name="dynamics_ord" value="<?php echo $this->getOrder()->getData('dynamics_ord'); ?>" style="width:150px; float:left; display:inline;" />
                <button onclick="editForm.submit()" style="float:left;margin:3px 10px 0;">Update</button>  
            </div> 
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            editForm = new varienForm('ord_form');
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**WACI_SalesExt_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Dynamicsord**

```
class WACI_SalesExt_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Dynamicsord extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('sales/ord_form.phtml');
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }

    public function getFormUrl(){
        return Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/sales_order/editord', array('order_id'=>$this->getOrder()->getId()) );
    }

}
```

**WACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController**

```
include_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Sales' . DS . 'OrderController.php';

class WACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{

    public function editordAction()
    {

        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        Mage::log('WACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController::ordEditAction'.print_r($postData, true) );

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        $order->setDynamicsOrd($postData['dynamics_ord']);

        $order->save();

        // return to sales_order view
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order/view", array('order_id'=> $id)));

    }

}
```

Been looking around for some info on this issue, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento) seems pretty close to what I want to do. But it's not clear that I'll be able to create an editable input via this workflow.

I'll note that I'm on Mage 1.11 - and I've gathered that the standard EAV pattern is no longer used for the order model.

Cheers -

---

#### Update

(note the "current" module contents.)

- The field has been added to the sales_flat_order
- WACI_SalesExt_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Dynamicsord block is getting constructed correctly
- i have some test data in place that is getting pulled in correctly

At this point, I don't think i have my router set up correctly. In your example, you called `<?php echo $this->getEditFormUrl(); ?>` . I'm not sure if that is supposed to output a formatted action url, but it wasn't. I dropped my own in, but its still not hitting the router correctly.

Currently, the value in the form action =

```
   action ="http://my.domain.com/index.php/my_admin/sales_order/editord/key/2e56d7f560dc4d356e3ef9519764b8a84858e5cd40d3c1f5821a423b949b9a6a/"
```

And just hits a "page not found". As far as I can tell, the router *should* be accurate here. I've tried a number of different combinations; I'm apparently missing something important on the admin router issue. I understand the `key/ee6`... is probably messing with me, but I'm not clear how to deal with it appropriately.

---

#### Update

Routing problem was simple error I was needlessly making complex: I had a miss-spelled directory name "AdminHtml" vs "Adminhtml" - causing the router to get lost.

Oh Magento...

Thanks @R.S. for teh help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try adding the 'editable input' to the 'Account Information' section on your order detail page.

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml

[image]

Add

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('salesext/adminhtml_editform')->setOrderId($_order->getId())->toHtml() ?>
```

In your block

```
<?php

class WACI_SalesExt_Block_Adminhtml_Editform extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
       $this->setTemplate('salesext/edit_form.phtml');
    }

    public function getOrder(){
        return Mage::registry('current_order');
    }

   public function getFormUrl(){
       return Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('*/sales_order/editField', array('order_id'=>$this->getOrder()->getId());
  }
  ...
```

in  /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/salesext/edit_form.phtml

```
<?php if ('sales_order' == Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() : ?>
<div id="change-order-email" style="display:none">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getEditFormUrl(); ?>" method="post" id="edit_form">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $this->getToken(); ?>" />  
        <table cellspacing="4" class="form-list">
            <tr>
                <td>Field</td>
                <td><input .... class="required-entry validate-email" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <button onclick="editForm.submit()">Change</button> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    editForm = new varienForm('edit_form');
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

In /app/code/local/CWACI/SalesExt/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

```
<?php
include_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Sales' . DS . 'OrderController.php';

class CWACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{

    public function editFieldAction()
    {
        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
        $order->setFieldName($postData[field_name]);
        .....
        $order->save();
```

In your config.xml

```
...
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <CWACI_SalesExt after="Mage_Adminhtml_Sales">CWACI_SalesExt_Adminhtml</CWACI_SalesExt>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>    
    </routers>
</admin>
```

.....

Also see [Setting custom Admin theme from a Module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) to prevent making modification directly to core templates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've been thinking about a number of ways to do this, and this might route might be very reasonable. I understand that the order model was moved from eav to flat (*sales_flat_order* correct?). Would you mind describing the logic flow of the controller a little more, in this case. Would this just be a manual update of that field in the sales_flat_order table? Maybe ajax would be useful here?

Comment: Hey - this looks like its going to work - having a couple issues still, if you have any thoughts (see update). Thanks a heap for the help ;)

Comment: I've only gotten halfway on this issue - the direction is great, but I need to open it back up for answers.

Comment: Hey there - check out my update block - I'm having issues with routing to the processor page (just bounces to 404).

Comment: Take a look at my update to confi.xml `...<CWACI_SalesExt after="Mage_Adminhtml_Sales">`

Comment: Also take a look @ `getFormUrl()`... Also make sure that you dont have any other module that extend `Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController`

Comment: Hi = thanks for your help on this - I updated the config and the getFormUrl method, but I'm still getting 404'd. That alan storm article makes it sound like the security key is going to cause problems, without a navigable page... do you know if that might be causing issues here?

Comment: I pull this code from a working example, so i know it work. According to your directory structure your controller is in the wrong path. Should be /app/code/local/CWACI/SalesExt/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

Comment: oh damn. nice catch. I had, at some point, added that directory into the mix (so - my directory notation isn't up to date) - but it was named "AdminHtml" instead of "Adminhtml". Sonofa.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23909/discussion-between-r-s-and-bosworth99)

Comment: Im was trying to reproduce this module but i cant understand very well, in some parts the class begin with CWACI and in other with WACI wich one is the correct?