# Magento - add custom attribute (column) to sales_order index grid

Tags: magento, gridview, attributes

I've added a custom attribute to the `sales_order_flat` table, and I'm trying to display this attribute in the grid at `sales_order/index`.

I've done this with customer attributes successfully, but I'm getting errors when trying the same thing with order data.

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>WACI_AdminHtmlExt_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
 <!-- etc  -->
```

**app/code/local/namespace/module/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php**

```
class WACI_AdminHtmlExt_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('dynamics_ord', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Dynamics ID'),
            'width'     => '75px',
            'index'     => 'dynamics_ord',
        ));

        $this->addColumnsOrder('dynamics_ord','entity_id');

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

I see that `_prepareCollection` is [sometimes used](http://www.atwix.com/magento/customize-orders-grid/), but I'm trying to just amend the collection during `setCollection` for, if nothing else, simplicity.

Whatever the case, the column displays, but no data is produced. (And the page errors out when I try to sort).

Any ideas on this?

#### Update

This post is an extension of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616499/magento-custom-order-attribute-admin-input-and-display) I've updated it to match the modules current status. That is, I'm adding columns to both `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid`.

From that post, I've got an action that takes place to set this attribute value (after the order has been completed).

My question at this point is - how does `updateGridRecords()` come into play?

**=> updateGridRecords appears to be called automatically when the $order->save() gets called (something I'm doing manually after the order is complete).**

If I understand this correctly, because I'm not pulling data from any other model, the `_prepareColumns` call is all that's required.

**=> yep. Displaying and sorting properly after the attr is saved. Win!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between customer collection and order grid collection is that customer collection is derived from Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract and sales_flat_order_grid collection is derived from Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract which is not EAV.

Because of that you can't add attributes to select like you would normaly be able to do with EAV - all the attributes that you want to use must be represented as a table column in the flat table.

The function addAttributeToSelect that you are calling is implemented in Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract class and uses in background addFieldToSelect so in you case you should have a column with name dynamics_ord in sales_flat_order_grid table.

The function that moves attribute values from order EAV to order grid is Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract::updateGridRecords and this function reads the structure of sales_flat_order_grid table to know which attributes should be written to sales_flat_order_grid table so if dynamics_ord column is missing you will have to add it in your module's install script.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento) stack overflow solution on how to add the column in install script and then add it to the grid. The answer is a bit outdated but I think it could work.

I have also found [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/260879/#t349572) out of the box solution on how to add an attribute that will be used on orders grid but haven't tested it so I can't be certain if it works.

Comment: great information. I'll spend some time with this and see what I find.

Comment: At this point just wondering if I need to manually call updateGridRecords (see my update).

Answer (score 0):

When you make a join EAV table with FLAT table then you can not filter the data in grid.
I had faced same problem earlier and had invested 4 days in that with my seniors, then finally come 2 conclusion that you can not do that....!!!

Comment: Actually you can do it but have to write your own joins (without using add attributeToSelect) with eav tables. At the end EAV tables are just a spread-over-multiple-tables data but database tables non the less.

Comment: yeah the article i linked to detailed how to do the joins, but in this case, the two tables are flat, and ended up being very easy to do.

Comment: @DomenVrankar : can you provide me brief explanation with some example, because it would help me a lot. Thnx.

Comment: You shouldn't ask a question inside another question but since it's related... In setCollection function you make a e.g. joinLeft on your collection. You add a column to grid with two additional attributes: 'filter_condition_callback' => array( $this, '_yourFilterFunc' ), 'filter' => 'adminhtml/widget_grid_column_filter_range' (or any other filter type). And then you write a filter function e.g.: protected function _yourFilterFunc( $collection, $column ){ $collection->addFieldToFilter( 'your_table_alias.' . $column->getIndex(), $column->getFilter()->getCondition() ); }.