# Magento 1.7.2 - Add custom field at Admin, Sales, Order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, ecommerce-sales

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method. At the end of step 2, I should see my field on Admin=>Sales=>Order but I can't see anything.

In sales_flat_quote_payment I can see the `telefono_no` field, and in `sales_flat_order_payment` too. When I buy something, Magento saves the phone data `telefono_no` in database. Anyway, my mysql4-install-0.1.0.php is:

```
$install = $this;
$install->startSetup();

$install->run("
    ALTER TABLE `".$install->getTable('sales/quote_payment')."` ADD `telefono_no` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000';
    ALTER TABLE `".$install->getTable('sales/order_payment')."` ADD `telefono_no` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000';
");

$install->endSetup();
```

And in my config.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Xs_Pago>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Xs_Pago>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_payment>
                <telefono_no>
                    <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
                </telefono_no>
            </sales_convert_quote_payment>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code about should only add the fields to the db and copy the value from quote_payment to order_payment when an order is place.

The code will not display any info, the reason the info is display in the example you refer is because of `Mage_Payment_Block_Info`

```
<?php
class Excellence_Pay_Block_Info_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{
    protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
            return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
        }
        $info = $this->getInfo();
        $transport = new Varien_Object();
        $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
        $transport->addData(array(
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Check No#') => $info->getCheckNo(),
            Mage::helper('payment')->__('Check Date') => $info->getCheckDate()
        ));
        return $transport;
    }
}
```

Take a look @ [Magento custom "order" attribute / admin input and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616499/magento-custom-order-attribute-admin-input-and-display/14617712#14617712)

Comment: Not if I understood your answer, you tell me that I am following the example is incomplete and that the only way to add a column in the table "sales - order" is creating a new template?

The code you posted, what is it for? where I have to put it? in my directory "Block"?

I followed your link but did not clarify anything.