# How to create new section in admin order view information tab?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create a new block in my admin panel "Sales->Order->View" Information tab.

In my extension's block folder i have a folder named Adminhtml in this i have file named : Company.php

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Company extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
{
 }
```

In my extension module i have placed this code in config.xml under etc folder

```
 <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <modulename>
                <file>module.xml</file>
            </modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
```

then i have my adminhtml layout file as :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
   <modulename_adminhtml_company_index>
    <reference name="order_info">
        <block type="modulename/adminhtml_company" name="modulename" template="company.phtml" />
    </reference>
   </modulename_adminhtml_company_index>
  </layout>
```

But nothing happened yet,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you are trying to accomplish

[image]

Take a look @ [Magento custom "order" attribute / admin input and display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616499/magento-custom-order-attribute-admin-input-and-display/14617712#14617712)

If you are trying to create a new tab take a look @ http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/custom-tabs-magento-product-admin/