# Adding a new custom input field in order > invoice magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I am trying to add new input field in `sales > order > invoice`. This would be like my reference number. This custom input field should be show in `sales > order >invoice & sales > invoice` and when I will print the invoice then this custom field need to be get showed. New custom grid need to get added, I am currently working with this [Link](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-attribute-to-magentos-pdf-invoice/comment-page-2/#comment-430300):

This extension is enable but custom filed is not showing up in `admin sales > order` .

Same with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento).

Can some one let me know how I need to proceed for this?

Comment: Can you please show what is the error you are getting in error log?

Comment: No error nothing is showing in admin panel sales > order.

Comment: which magento version are you using?

Comment: i am using magento 1.7.1 .  checked with both sales > order and sales > invoice . the custom field is not showing up . 
If possible can you explain me how can proceed for this issue ,
1) Custom field in invoice when order add to invoice .
2) Once submit invoice , we can search the custom invoice number in sales > invoice grid .

Comment: first, better to upgrade magento then work. second, I have not asked to check error in sales > order. I have asked you to check in error log file.
Third, You have to check in controller files. track the code and debug that.

Comment: Yep Sure will do an upgrade my shop . Tried with this extension reached some how the requirement : http://magentodownload.net/free-magento-extensions/custom-invoice-number/

Actual this extension override the default invoice number and showing the custom invoice number in sales> invoice  , but i am trying to get in a new grid call invoice ref number , Can you update me how can i move forward on this.

Comment: Because of patched work override occurred. You should make own extension

Comment: Hi Again, I had get the custome input field in new grid , So my ref number added to Ref id , Please check this screenshot for more info : http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/271206/91487ae6a89516c496a64776cdefdf6f
But i can not able to get my actual invoice id in invoice # grid ,

Comment: Is it inserting in database? have you had checked?

Comment: '$this->addColumn('invoice_increment_id',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice #'),
                'index' => 'invoice_increment_id',
                'type=' => 'number',     
            ));
    $this->addColumn('increment_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Reference Id'),
        'index'     => 'increment_id',
        'type'      => 'text',
      )); '

Comment: Yes will check in db and let you know , sorry i am not able to format the code in proper way  in  comments . the above code i am used to get the ref id . I am trying to show up the invoice increment id in Invoice # grid.

Comment: I am not able to find the custome  invoice id in db , Can you please let me know how can i find that exactly .