# Magento custom order attribute not saving to database

Tags: php, magento

I have followed [this question for adding a custom attribute to Magento orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento).

I want to set the value of this attribute programmatically but its not saving to the database. My code:

```
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$_order->loadByIncrementId(100000001);
$_order->setMyCustomField('Testing');
$_order->save();
```

I have also tried:

```
$_order->setData('my_custom_field','Testing');
```

I have checked that the field exists in the `sales_flat_order` table
.

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Answer (score -1):

I have now resolved this issue. I'm using XAMPP and found I needed to both restart Apache and use the "Flush Cache Storage" option in Magento.

Following this the value is saving correctly.