# Magento Add value in custom column of sales_flat_order table

Tags: magento

Hi i have made a custom column in **sales_flat_order** table named **final_shipping_amount**. When i am loading order its showing my custom column in it. I am trying to add value in my custom column but its not adding value in it here is my code.

```
$final_shipping = "1.33"
$orderIid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$orderDataShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIid);
$orderDataShip->setFinalShippingAmount($final_shipping);
$orderDataShip->save();
```

Its not saving value in it. i have also tried this way but also its not saving

```
$final_shipping = "1.33"
$orderIid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
$orderDataShip = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIid);
$orderDataShip->setData('final_shipping_amount' , $final_shipping);
$orderDataShip->save();
```

but its not working.

Comment: are you using this code in an event?

Comment: i am using this code on shipment form submit.

Comment: try to use `sales_order_place_before` event and use your code in observer's function that worked for me

Comment: You're saving the order entity there, which doesn't save to the flat order table it will save the order to the EAV entity structure- you need to tell magento you've added the new attribute

Answer (score 0):

In your module's config.xml file user this event

```
<sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <Yournamespace_YourModuleName_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Yournamespace_YourModuleName_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>example</method>
                </Yournamespace_YourModuleName_model_observer>
            </observers>
</sales_order_place_before>
```

And in your Observer file

```
public function example($observer) {
        $final_shipping = "1.33";
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();


        $items = $order->getQuote()->getAllItems(); 
        //Mage::log($items->debug());

        $orderdata = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getEntityId());
        $mn = $orderdata->setData('final_shipping_amount', $final_shipping );
        $orderdata->save();

    }
```

May be it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an attribute to magento isn't as simple as that.

Firstly when you save the order entity, magento will save this into the EAV structure not the flat order table.

You need to tell magento you've added a new attribute first, there's a load of info on how to do this for example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento
```

Once you've done that magento will be aware of the attribute you've added and should save correctly.